# Using [ nohup ksh ] to run a script cannot see the sleep process

Tags: sleep, ksh

I am using CentOS 7.6 and bash shell inside VirtualBox .

I came across a script named MotherScript in my site having this statement :

```
nohup ksh MyScript &
```

Both MotherScript and MyScript have a shebang line

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

After login, I just fire the MotherScript.

In my previous companies, usually, I used this statement :

```
nohup MyScript &
```

Is there any functional/strange/usage difference between these 2 statements ?

Inside MyScript, there is a `sleep` command to sleep 1 hour repeatedly in a while loop for 7 days.

However, very strange, I cannot see this sleep process using :

```
ps -ef | grep sleep
```

Therefore, I cannot kill the sleep process.

Does this `nohup ksh` play the trick ?

Anyone know the reason behind ?

Thanks.
Alvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to your issue could be to launch the script using bash instead of ksh. ksh does not seem to generate a PID/process for the sleep...

The reasoning behind this "feature" of ksh would be very interesting to hear about.

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup ksh MyScript &
```

This will run the script using ksh(korn) shell.

```
nohup MyScript &
```

This will pick your default shell which you can check using below command

```
echo $SHELL
```

you can also change default shell using **chsh** Utility

Comment: Sorry, I have not describe my problem more detail.  I have re-edit the question.  Actually, both scripts have a shebang line.